# how do you filter over property of object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects.  each object has a name and a value.  I need to return an array that just has the names where value equals the maximum.

Comment: Have you any example data to show? At the moment the question is quite generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.filter(function (element) {
  return element.value === MAXIMUM;
}).map(function (element) {
  return element.name;
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I couldn't figure this out. But I see now that element is the object in the array

Answer (score 2):

```
array.filter(element => element.value === MAXIMUM).map(element => element.name);
```

Comment: can you possibly rewrite this without the arrow notation?

Comment: I rewrote it without braces, should be more readable.
By the way, what is the problem with lambda expressions? Defining a function instead would be an overkill.

Comment: @DCR Can you possibly show some code and do some of your own work?